# how to place a table in the center of the browser

Tags: jquery-mobile

[image]
I'm working on Mobile app.I have a Div in that i have created a table , which i want to be in center if i change the browser size. 
what i tried is:

```
   <div data-role="content"

<div align="center" height:50px; ">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td width="20%"><img src="images/1.png" ></td>
      <td width="80%"  ><a href="#" class="custom-btn" data-role="button" data-    mini="true">sunday</a></td>
    </tr>
   </table>
</div>
<br>
<div align="center"  height:50px;">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td width="20%"><img src="images/3.png" ></td>
      <td width="80%"  ><a href="#" data-role="button" class="custom-btn" data-mini="true">Monday</a></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The CSS `margin: 0 auto;` will center the table.

Give the table a class name (e.g. centeredTable):

```
<div>
    <table class="centeredTable">
        <tr>
            <td><img src="http://lorempixel.com/26/26/food/1/" /></td>
            <td><a href="#" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all custom-btn ui-shadow ui-mini">sunday</a></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Then create the CSS rule:

```
.centeredTable {
    margin: 0 auto;
}

<!-- optional rules for vertical center, first td 20%, last td 80% -->
.centeredTable td{
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.centeredTable tr td:first-child{
    width: 20%;
}
.centeredTable tr td:last-child{
    width: 80%;
}
```

> Here is a **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/GP3QS/)**

Comment: @ ezanker : Thanku for your valuable reply. But as i change the browser size, div size is reducing.

Comment: I'm trying for this
<div style="background-color:#foo;">
    <table class="centeredTable">
        <tr>
            <td><img src="http://lorempixel.com/26/26/food/1/" /></td>
            <td><a href="#" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all custom-btn ui-shadow ui-mini">sunday</a></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>

Comment: if you want the DIV to have a set width, be centered, and have the table fill the DIV, try this: http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/GP3QS/1/

Comment: I would like to add another image outside of the div.
But if i add ,div will be no more center.

Comment: @user3632072, how do you want it to look? Where exactly would you like the new image to be?

Comment: @ ezanker , as in image, but i couldnot align it

Comment: @user3632072, you are not being clear.  Should the image be in the same horizontal line as the div/table? or do you want it above the div and centered? maybe edit my last fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/GP3QS/1/, or post an image of the end result you want.

Comment: @ ezanker, yes exactly , i want another image to be in the same horizontal line as the div/table

Comment: @ ezanker , thanks a lot :) worked like a charm.. :)